# How to create a custom function to find the determinant of 3x3 matrix

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I know that det(A) is in matlab.

I want to do a function that take a matrix A(3x3) and returns the determinant.
I know it's dumb but it's for understanding functions.

My attempt:

```
function [myDet] = myDet(a)
  myDet = a(1,1) * (a(2,2) * a(3,3) - a(3,2) * a(2,3))
        - a(1,2) * (a(2,1) * a(3,3) - a(3,1) * a(2,3))
        + a(1,3) * (a(2,1) * a(3,2) - a(3,1) * a(2,2))
endfunction
```

Comment: Hm the expansion along the first row seems right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using GNU/Octave ...

First, semantic is probably not the one you meant. It is

```
function [ <output> ] = <function_identifier> ( <input> )
```

Hence

```
function [ d ] = myDet ( A )
```

Then, apparently multiple line statements fails to be evaluated as a single instruction. I solved this way

```
function [ d ] = myDet ( A )

    ## If A is a 3x3 matrix, compute the determinant as follows ... 
    if size(A) == [3,3]
        d = A(1,1) * (A(2,2) * A(3,3) - A(3,2) * A(2,3)) + \
            - A(1,2) * (A(2,1) * A(3,3) - A(3,1) * A(2,3)) + \
            + A(1,3) * (A(2,1) * A(3,2) - A(3,1) * A(2,2));
    ## ... else, use the default function ...
    else
        d = det(A)
    endif
end
```

#### Note

I've changed the name of your output variable (from `myDet` to `d`) since in general is not good practice calling the output of a function as the name you give the procedure. In Octave (ehm ...Matlab) this sounds to have no consequences, but remind there are some programming languages where you can directly handle functions by their identifier (I'm thinking of Javascript, for instance).

Comment: Hello, I tested your suggestion and it works for little numbers, but when I put A=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9] myDet(A) = 0 but det(A) is something else.

Comment: @beorn, trying to reproduce your situation `det(A)` returns `-9.5171e-16` while `myDet(A)` returns `0`. I would consider them pretty the same number. Course, the algorithm implemented by Octave is far more precise than the one I tried above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function [y] = myDet(A)
      y = A(1,1) * (A(2,2) * A(3,3) - A(3,2) * A(2,3)) \
        - A(1,2) * (A(2,1) * A(3,3) - A(3,1) * A(2,3)) \
        + A(1,3) * (A(2,1) * A(3,2) - A(3,1) * A(2,2));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MATLAB close at hand, but I think you'll need a space in 'end function'. Other than that, it looks good. I'd put in some error checking that size(a) = 3 3. (Actually, you don't really need 'end' at all if it's in its own file. And it's 'end', not 'end function'). The return value should be just 'myDet'

```
function out = myDet(a)
out = a(1,1) * (a(2,2) * a(3,3) - a(3,2) * a(2,3))
  - a(1,2) * (a(2,1) * a(3,3) - a(3,1) * a(2,3))
  + a(1,3) * (a(2,1) * a(3,2) - a(3,1) * a(2,2))
end
```

Changed output variable to 'out' so that you don't have a method and variable by the same name. That can get hairy.